# Почему удаляется только в обратном порядке?

Tags: php, mysql

Я вывожу из БД данные создаю после цикла  кнопку удалить, и название(из БД). Далее ниже говорится что если нажата кнопка с определенным названием кнопки, то удалить запись из бд, но если создать больше 1й такой записи, а потом пытаться удалить сначала первую, а потом вторую, то ничего не происходит, удаляется только в обратном порядке создания, то есть сначала вторая, потом первая. Почему так?

```
<?php $sql = mysqli_query($conn3,"SELECT * FROM `Food`");?>
<?php foreach($sql as $row):?>
<?php 
    $dish = $row['dish_name'];
    $id = $row['id'];
?>
<div>
    <h1 class="red" ><?php echo $dish;?></h1> 
    <input type="submit" class="del" name="<?php echo $id;?>" value="Удалить">
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST[$id])){
        $conn3->query("DELETE FROM `Food` WHERE id= '$id'");}
?>
```

Comment: Потому что ты делаешь цикл по всем записям  и в `$id` у тебя хранится значение после последней итерации цикла

Comment: А вообще ты сам же писал ответ на свой вопрос ранее ( https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1523693/191482 ). Текущая версия html и получение айдишника - неправильная, но ты упорно пытаешься делать по-старому. по неправильному

Comment: Да, я сделал точно так же как и в своём ответе, но мне не нравиться постоянно использовать get, вы говорили, что можно было оставить post, но я так и не врубился как. И как вы узнали версию Html?

Comment: *"можно было оставить post, но я так и не врубился как"* --- как как. Вместо GET пишешь POST.  и вместо method="get" пишешь method="post"

Answer (score 0):

Немного исправленный и более правильный вариант решения твоего запроса. Но у тебя кажется очень сильно хромают основы. Крайне рекомендую перед выполнением боевых задач пройтись по ним. От себя рекомендую PHP в подлиннике, как раз недавно вышла новая часть.

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($conn3, "SELECT * FROM `Food`");

foreach ($sql as $row) {
    $dish = $row['dish_name'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    ?>
    <div>
        <h1 class="red"><?php echo $dish; ?></h1>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <input type="submit" class="del" name="delete_<?php echo $id; ?>" value="Удалить">
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $deleteId = $_POST['id'];
    if (isset($_POST['delete_' . $deleteId])) {
        $stmt = $conn3->prepare("DELETE FROM `Food` WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $deleteId);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
?>
```